# Creating sorted tree in DOJO 1.6?

Tags: dojo

I new to learn dojo and trying to learn by it using samples code.
Using dojo 1.6

With help of sample codes , I created a tree

[image]

now i want to apply sorting on root and also on child.
With the help of this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AnxBW/) code , i changed the code

Output is not sorted n but the root folder has changed their position and child is deleted.

Plz help me to resolve this.

My code :

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel");
dojo.require("dijit.Tree");
var data = [ { id: 1, name: "answerTypeLabel",                 type:'scenario',    children:[{_reference: 2}]},
                       { id: 2, name: "acceptRequestLabel",             type:'paragraph',   data: "acceptRequestLabel"},
                       { id: 3, name: "rejectRequestLabel",             type:'scenario',    children:[{_reference: 5},{_reference: 6}]},
                       { id: 4, name: "MoreInformationLabel",       type:'scenario',    children:[{_reference: 7},{_reference: 8}]},
                       { id: 5, name: "rejectRequestStatusLabel",   type:'paragraph',   data: "rejectRequestStatusLabel"},
                       { id: 6, name: "rejectRequestNotCoveredLabel", type:'paragraph',     data: "rejectRequestNotCoveredLabel" },
                       { id: 7, name: "MoreInformationDocumentLabel", type:'paragraph',     data: "MoreInformationDocumentLabel"},
                       { id: 8, name: "MoreInformationDataLabel",   type:'paragraph',   data: "MoreInformationDataLabel"}
                     ];
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var sortableStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        data: {
              identifier: 'id',
                        label: 'name',
                        items: data 
        }
    });
    var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
        rootLabel: 'Names',
        store: new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
            data: {
                identifier: 'id',
                items: [],
                label: 'name'
            }
        }) // blank itemsstore
    })
    var tree = new dijit.Tree({
        model: model,
        updateItems: function(items) {
            var self = this;
            console.log('pre', this.model.root.children);

            dojo.forEach(items, function(newItem) {
                console.log('add', newItem);
                try {
                    self.model.store.newItem({
                        id: sortableStore.getValue(newItem, 'id'),
                        name: sortableStore.getValue(newItem, 'name'),
                        type: sortableStore.getValue(newItem, 'type'),
                        data: sortableStore.getValue(newItem, 'data'),

                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
            console.log('post', this.model.root.children);
            console.log("children: ", this.rootNode.getChildren());

        },
    });
    tree.placeAt(dojo.body());
    sortableStore.fetch({
        query: {
            type:'scenario' 
        },
        sort: [{
            attribute: "name"}],
        onComplete: function(items) {
            console.log(items, 'sorted');
            tree.updateItems(items);

        }
    })
});
```

Output : [image: output of above code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Names' origins from you setting 'rootLabel'.

Btw, fiddles have revisions and is simply a paste-bin like feature :)

You need to use the tree model `pasteItem` to insert referenced items (the 'children' property of each 'newItem').

Otherwise, there's another approach, if you get rid of the '_reference' structure of your data. See: http://jsfiddle.net/GHFdA/1/

Comment: : `store._arrayOfTopLevelItems` is a private property of a store and one should not use it. Somebody suggested to use fetch. but i dont understand how to use it. can you please help.

Comment: please help me with this.with fetch i can get only root data sorted not the child. How to get child data sorted.

Comment: prso trust me, its safe enough - for ItemFile**Store's. To achieve same via .fetch: pass {query: {'type': 'scenario'}, onComplete: cb} as parameter in your case. Problem is, fetch may be async and that will not work well with the proposed solution